# How can i use BufferedWaveProvider to resolve this

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm using `BufferedWaveProvider` to creating a sound project.
for example, i have a `byte[]` of wave data
i want to add it to the buffer many times, and each time i will add 2000 bytes.
In the first time when i add 2000 bytes to the buffer, the `waveout.Play()` is started too.(asynchronous) When the `waveout` read to the 1500th byte, i will add more 2000 bytes, more 2000 bytes when `waveout` read to 1500th-byte of the second 2000 bytes...until complete the `byte[]` of wave data.

Can this be achieved with **NAudio**.
Please give some solutions for this.
Thank you very much.
Below is my code example

```
public async Task StartDummySoundSource(BufferedWaveProvider provider)
        {
            // check if total of data is buffered
            endFlag = 0;
            do
            {
                   // i will get 2000bytes of wave data here(it is below of btmp)
            if(the byte[] is run out)
            {
            endFlag = 1;
            }
                provider.AddSamples(btmp, 0, r * sizeof(short));
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
            while (endFlag == 0);
```

And when click the Play button:

```
private void playBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 2));

        Task t = StartDummySoundSource(bufferedWaveProvider);

        wavPlayer.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);

        wavPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: i cant know when the wave out read to 1500th byte to add more 2000 bytes, i dont know the way to get the exactly current position.